# Why outputting 'error: ' in Post-Build Event breaks my build in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event, targets

Adding

```
cmd.exe /c "ECHO error : unexplainable"
```

causes this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: xxx, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>EXEC : error : unexplainable
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: The command "cmd.exe /c "ECHO error : unexplainable"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It happens only when 'error' string is followed by a ':' character.

Comment: cmd.exe /c ECHO "error : explainable"

Comment: @HansPassant WOW MUCH LAUGH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in MSBuild: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/766

The 'Exec' task used by the 'PostBuildEvent' target should have the 'IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat' set to true by default but it doesn't, so it fails when finding 'error:' in the output.

<s>An unreliable way to fix this is to modify the 'PostBuildEvent' target in
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets` (at line 134) by adding `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"` to the 'Exec' task</s>

Override predefined 'PostBuildEvent' in your project like here: [Can I include a .targets file in a .props property sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436524/can-i-include-a-targets-file-in-a-props-property-sheet)